# The only way to obtain ether is generate the ether?

Tags: ether, mining, wallets, exchanges, coinbase

Hello i have a question :

- The only way to get ether is buying to another user has mining the ether ?

let me explain my question, i know i can use coinbase or another websites to buy ether, but where that ethers come from?, the only way to get the ether is mining?, and coinbase is a trading system to buy and sell ether that was mined ?

thanks a lot for reading <3

Comment: The only way to **generate** ether is to mine it. In order to **get** ether, you can either mine it, or ask it from someone else who has mined it.

Comment: And since you can replace the word "generate" above with "mine", the entire question becomes redundant.

Comment: sorry my english is bad , thanks for reading and answer <3

Comment: Your English here looks good enough to me (except for the `<3` you keep adding, not really sure what that one means).

Comment: the "<3" is a heart